Does isometry preserve volume
Let $(M,g)$ be an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold and $\pi:\bar{M}\rightarrow M$ be the universal covering space. Suppose $Ric_M\geq (n-1)k$ for some constant $k$. Now, Bishop-Gromov volume comparison theorem says that if $B_r(p)\subset M$ is a geodesic ball with center at $p\in M$ and radius $r>0$, then
\begin{equation}\label{e1}
Vol(B_r(p))\leq Vol(B^k_r),
\end{equation}
where $B^k_r$ is the geodesic ball of radius $r$ in a manifold of constant curvature $k$. Since $\pi$ is a local isometry, does it imply that geodesic ball in $\bar{M}$ also satisfies the above volume inequality?

Note that isometry preserves the Riemann curvature tensor, so it also preserves the sectional curvature, Ricci tensor and scalar curvature. Thus ${\rm Ric}_\bar M={\rm Ric}_M\geq(n-1)k$, and the geodesic ball in $\bar{M}$ also satisfies the displayed volume inequality.
In fact, the components of the Riemann curvature tensor $R=R^{i}{ }_{j k l} \partial_{i} \otimes d x^{j} \otimes d x^{k} \otimes d x^{l}$  in a local coordinate can be expressed as:
$$R^{i}{ }_{j k l}=\Gamma^{i}{ }_{j l, k}-\Gamma^{i}{ }_{j k, l}+\Gamma^{i}{ }_{\alpha k} \Gamma^{\alpha}{ }_{j l}-\Gamma^{i}{ }_{\alpha l} \Gamma^{\alpha}{ }_{j k}.$$
By the definition of Christoffel symbol, it is intrinsic, that is, isometry preserves Christoffel symbol, so is Riemann curvature tensor.
